# Filter list with 2 dropdowns

Tags: c#, linq, listview, filtering

I have 2 dropdowns and a listview:

```
<option value="Please choose...">Please choose...</option>
<option value="Permanent">Permanent</option>
<option value="Part Time">Part Time</option>
<option value="Volunteer">Volunteer</option>
<option value="Temporary">Temporary</option>

<option value="Please choose...">Please choose...</option>
<option value="South West">South West</option>
<option value="South East">South East</option>
<option value="London">London</option>
<option value="East of England">East of England</option>
<option value="West Midlands">West Midlands</option>
<option value="East Midlands">East Midlands</option>
<option value="North West">North West</option>
<option value="North East">North East</option>
<option value="Yorkshire &amp; Humberside">Yorkshire &amp; Humberside</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
<option value="Midlands">Midlands</option>
```

I would like to filter a list of items with these 2 dropdown values. If index 0 is selected (Please choose) this should return all for that property.

This is the code I have, but when you select something from the second dropdown, the results are not correct.

```
protected void LoadCareerList(string jobType = "", string jobLocation = "")
    {
        var currentNode = Node.GetCurrent();
        var nodeList = new List<Node>();
        lblVacancyCount.Text = "Current vacancies: 0";

        foreach (Node node in currentNode.Children)
        {
            nodeList.Add(node);
        }

        if (nodeList.Count > 0)
        {
            List<Node> filteredList = nodeList.Where(
                    x => ((ddlFilterType.SelectedIndex == 0 || x.GetProperty("jobType").Value.Replace(" ", "").ToLower().Contains(jobType.Replace(" ", "").ToLower()))) && ((ddlFilterLocation.SelectedIndex == 0 || x.GetProperty("jobLocation").Value.Replace(" ", "").ToLower().Contains(jobLocation.Replace(" ", "").ToLower())))).OrderByDescending(x => x.GetProperty("jobDatePosted").Value).ToList();

            lvCareers.DataSource = filteredList;
            lvCareers.DataBind();
            lblVacancyCount.Text = "Current vacancies: " + filteredList.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        }
    }
```

I have 3 records in the system so far:
Career 1 = Midlands & Permanent
Career 2 = London & Permanent
Career 3 = Midlands & Temporary
When I select Permanent I get 2 records, choosing London in the 2nd filter returns 0 records.

Comment: The filtering code looks correct to me. I assume that you are passing in the selected value of ddlFilterLocation in jobLocation when calling LoadCareerList. Have you verified this is the correct value when London is selected? If so then perhaps the data for Career 2 is incorrect. Can you confirm?

Comment: I assume the first set of options aer for `ddlFilterType` and the second set for `ddlFilterLocation`?

Comment: Are you sure that `currentNode` actually has children in that case and that `nodeList.Count()` is > 0?

Comment: Thanks odyssseus.section9, it was a combination of the wrong field being checked jobLocation should have been jobArea, and my calling method was only passing in jobType and not jobType & job Location...argh !!!